# Find the likelihood threshold for a Goodness-of-Fit test for multinomial data

Tags: statistics, computational-mathematics

Given a sample size $n \in \mathbb{N}$, a null hypothesis $H_0 = \langle p_1, p_2, \dots p_k\rangle$ which is an element of the $k$-dimensional probability simplex, and a significance threshold $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, let $D \sim \mathop{Mult}_k(n, H_0)$, in other words, let $D$ be drawn from the multinomial distribution with $n$ trials and event probabilities $ p_1, p_1, \dots p_k$.

Then, there exists some maximal $t \in (0,1)$ such that $\Pr\limits_D[\mathcal{L}(H_0|D) < t] \leq \alpha$, i.e., such that the probability of the event "the likelihood of $D$ occuring as the result of a draw from a multinomial distribution distributed under $H_0$ is less than t" is less than or equal to $\alpha$.

How can I find this $t$ efficently?  I can find it with a greedy search of all possible values of $D$, but that's extremely slow ($O(n^k)$), and I can find an approximate value for it with Monte Carlo.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe you could try https://stats.stackexchange.com for stats questions.

Comment: that's a good idea, thanks - wasn't aware that existed

Comment: $\mathcal{L}(D \mid H_0)$ looks odd to me : likelihood is only defined up to proportionality and would usually be for a parameter (or model) given an observation rather than the other way round

Comment: @Henry you're correct that it was backwards, but likelihood is perfectly well defined outside of as a proportion, it's just not often used that way, I think